# Trying to read a csv file with thailand's character in it using php but after reading it the characters are changed to some unidentified characters

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding

I have a csv file that have data like this:

```
Sub District    District
A Hi อาฮี        Tha Li District ท่าลี่
A Phon อาโพน    Buachet District บัวเชด
```

when I tried to read it using php code by following this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474031/importing-csv-with-asian-characters-in-php):

```
<?php
//set internal encoding to utf8
mb_internal_encoding('utf8');

$fileContent = file_get_contents('thai_unicode.csv');

//convert content from unicode to utf
$fileContentUtf = mb_convert_encoding($fileContent, 'utf8', 'unicode');

echo "parse utf8 string:\n";
var_dump(str_getcsv($fileContentUtf, ';'));
```

But it didn't work at all. Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your code:

- Your code applies str_getcsv to whole file contents (instead of individual line)
- Your code example is using delimiter ";" but there is no such symbol in your input file.

Your data is in either fixed field length format (which is actually not a csv file) or in tab delimited csv file format.

If it is tab delimited file format then you can use 2 ways to read your file:

```
$lines = file('thai_unicode.csv');

foreach($lines as $line){
    $data =  str_getcsv($line,"\t");
    echo "sub_district: ". $data[0].", district: ".$data[1]."\n";
}
```

or

```
$f = fopen('thai_unicode.csv',"r");
while($data = fgetcsv($f,0,"\t")){
    echo "sub_district: ". $data[0].", district: ".$data[1]."\n";
}
fclose($f);
```

And in case you have fixed length fields data format you need to split each line yourself because csv related php function are not suitable for this purpose.
So you will end up with something like this:

```
$f = fopen('thai_unicode.csv',"r");
while($line = fgets($f)){
    $sub_district = mb_substr($line,0,20);
    $district = mb_substr($line,20);
    echo "sub_district: $sub_district, district: $district\n";
}
fclose($f);
```